# The delete button should only remove the current widget

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to delete individual widgets but when I hit the delete button all of the widgets are deleted

I have tried to use *ngFor but not sure if my implementation is correct

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9quulu

The delete button should only remove the current widget

Comment: You have an array of 4 elements. You want to remove one element. That won't happen by setting a global delete flag to true. It will hapen by... removing an element from the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to delete an item from array it's using splice.

Add in the NgFor the following declaration: **let i = index** to indicate to **deleteWidget()** method the index that you want to delete:

```
    <div class="af-notification" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [class.toggled]="toggled">
  <div class="af-notification__content"  [class.delete]="delete">
    <button (click)="deleteWidget(i)" class="btn-close">delete</button>
    <span class="af-notification__title" [class.read]="item['read'] == true">{{ item['title'] }}</span>
    <span class="af-notification__description">{{ item['description'] }}</span>
    <span class="af-notification__date-time">
      {{ item['date'] }} {{ item['time'] }}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your deleteWidget method should be:

```
deleteWidget(i) {
    this.items.splice(i, 1)
  }
```